# Entity Framework 6 does not recognize mapped function in database model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, devart

I have a problem with Entity Developer and model defined function. Ealier I was mapping functions as a stored procedures because Entity Developer has no support for database functions as it goes. I was using solution mentioned in this [topic from devart forum](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=17083). But it has no use for me now, because I can't use it in `Linq` query as a part of bigger select statement on entity.

I am trying to add function like [this](http://blog.devart.com/model-defined-functions-in-entity-developer.html?_ga=1.193775533.1888614147.1472728891) and make it the way it is mentioned [here](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=31557). But i am getting this exception

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] EwBlobIleWyst(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

In ssdl file function is generated like this:

```
<Function Name="EW_BLOB_ILE_WYST" IsComposable="true" ReturnType="decimal" BuiltIn="false" Aggregate="false" NiladicFunction="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="EWID4" StoreFunctionName="EW_BLOB_ILE_WYST">
<Parameter Name="OWNER" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
<Parameter Name="OWNER_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
<Parameter Name="RODZ_DOK_IDS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
<Parameter Name="LICZ_PUSTE" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
```

In csdl file it is like this :

```
<Function Name="EwBlobIleWyst" ReturnType="Collection(Int32)" ed:Guid="f544518f-1cdd-484c-92b4-73b61491dc54">
<Parameter Name="OWNER" Type="String" />
<Parameter Name="OWNER_ID" Type="Int32" />
<Parameter Name="RODZ_DOK_DS" Type="String" />
<Parameter Name="LICZ_PUSTE" Type="Int32" />
<DefiningExpression>SELECT EWID4.EW_BLOB_ILE_WYST(:OWNER, :OWNER_ID, :RODZ_DOK_IDS, :LICZ_PUSTE) FROM KDOK_WSK</DefiningExpression>
```

And my implementation looks like this :

```
    [EdmFunction(@"Ewid4", @"EwBlobIleWyst")]
    public virtual global::System.Nullable<int> EwBlobIleWyst(string OWNER, global::System.Nullable<int> OWNER_ID, string RODZ_DOK_IDS, global::System.Nullable<int> LICZ_PUSTE)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

This code is inside partial context class.
And I am using it in this way :

```
DokPow = ((Ewid4)context).EwBlobIleWyst("smth", 1, null, 0)
```

This snippet is inside select of queryable using Linq

Answer (score 2):

I just get a solution. The problem was in attribute, database namespace generated by Entity Developer and function and variables types.
I had to make something like that:

```
    [DbFunction("Ewid.Database.Entities.Store", "EW_BLOB_ILE_WYST")]
    public static decimal EwBlobIleWyst(string OWNER, decimal OWNER_ID, string RODZ_DOK_IDS, decimal LICZ_PUSTE)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

And change types to types that was genereted in ssdl file, csdl file does not matter and there is no need in adding function in Entity Developer to model, just leave it in ssdl file and map this function by hand in c# and it works like a charm.